# How do method arguments work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I can't seem to find an answer to this question, and the two books I've checked seem to be written for experienced programmers who are new to Ruby, not beginners to programming *as well as* Ruby.  I'm struggling to understand how method arguments work and what their purpose is. For example, this I can understand:

```
def method_name
  # method behaviour
end
```

Then, whenever I want to re-use that particular batch of code, I simply re-enter method_name and Ruby will repeat the actions as specified in that method. However, most methods I've seen include arguments in parenthesis immediately following the name, i.e.

```
def method_name (argument1, argument2)
  # method behaviour
end
```

I'm struggling to grasp what the arguments mean and how they factor into the functionality of the code. Also, why are arguments required for some methods but not others? Do arguments represent input from the user? Are they similar to params?

Comment: IMHO, this should be covered in any basic tutorial or book.

Comment: _Sidenote_: the space between method name and opening parenthesis is strongly not encouraged in ruby.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]". This is a basic part of programming and is best answered by tutorials and books. Stack Overflow is not a replacement for you reading and searching.

Comment: @theTinMan Do you know a good book for beginners to programming as well as Ruby? I've purchased The Ruby Programming Language by David Flanagan as well as The Well Grounded Rubyist by David Black but both seem to be geared toward people who already know how to program, even if they're new to Ruby.

Comment: @JesseSielaff https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#parens-no-spaces

Comment: @JesseSielaff There is a reason for that: `def par a;  puts a; end; par (42) / 2 #⇒ 21`. I bet you expected `par` to be called with `42` as an argument, but with a space it is called with `21`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods have the option of taking arguments and it's up to you the designer whether or not to include this option. Sometimes it just makes sense to include this option, sometimes not. You will see this as you code more.

**Example without argument**

```
def say_hello
  puts "hello"
end

#calling the method
say_hello #=> hello
```

This method is simply designed to say hello when called, which works fine.

**Example with argument**

```
def say_personal_hello(name)
  puts "hello #{name}"
end

#calling the method with an argument
say_personal_hello("mszub") #=> hello mszub
```

But this method takes an argument because I want it to be personalised by putting a particular name in it. The name can be a user input if you like for example:

```
puts "What's your name?"
input_name = gets.chomp

def say_personal_hello(input_name)
  puts "hello #{input_name}"
end

say_personal_hello(input_name)
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: @mszub try running the last example (save it in a file say `example3.rb` then run it in the terminal with the `ruby example3.rb` command and you'll see how it works. Also if you found any answer particularly useful be sure to click the relevant 'grey tick' for that answer so it turns green.

Comment: @ sagarpandya82 I'll give it a try, thanks! Also, I tried to click the upwards grey tick on your reply but it said I don't have a big enough reputation to do so yet. Many thanks, regardless. I really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2):

Like you said, think of the arguments like parameters (the two words are used for slightly different meanings but it's not important for your understanding at this point.)

The arguments are input to be used in the method behavior.

```
def add(arg1, arg2)
    sum = arg1 + arg2
    return sum
end
```

Then you can call that method with some arguments:

```
result = add(1, 2)
# result equals 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Function arguments don't just apply to Ruby.

Think for example a mathematical function `f(x) = x^2`, where `x` is the input and the function simply uses that input to return an output, in this case `x` squared.

This concept applies to programming across many languages where arguments can be used to specify a contract between the function and the caller of the function to modify the behavior of the function.

In ruby the above mathematical function could be defined as:

```
def square(x)
  x ** 2
end 

square(3) #=> 9
square(4) #=> 16
```